# Appendix equation references in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

On MS Word, I've got a document with two appendices, titled as "APPENDIX A" and "APPENDIX B".
Within these appendices, there are some figures and equations. Is there any way to have the figure and equation numbers to be automatically based on the appendix title?

For example:

```
Fig. A.1,...,Fig. A.5, 
Fig. B.1,...,Fig. B.5, 
Eq. (A.1),...,Eq. (A.5),
```

where if somewhere down the road, if I decide to switch the contents of appendix A and B around, the Fig. and Eq. references would also automatically change with it.

Comment: Have you looked into StyleRef fields? If the titles of Appendix A and Appendix B carried unique style names, you could insert StyleRef fields as part of the Figure or Equation caption label.

Comment: @RichMichaels I'm currently using "{STYLEREF 1 \s}" to preceed my equation or figure number, but it still shows up as a number rather than a letter. For instance, in "APPENDIX A", the first figure is displayed as "Fig. 6.1", rather than "Fig. A.1".

Comment: @RichMichaels Also to add, I used the same StyleRef fields for previous chapters of my document, like within CHAPTER 5, my first figure is displayed as "Fig. 5.1".